# AWS Glue - changing column to type array or struct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I've started using AWS Glue to read some files on S3 recently.

After having spent many hours to get correct crawler I have three tables. One of them is called `raw`. It contains csv files  in folders split by year/month/date

The schema that was created shows one particular column `event_features` as `string`.

However when running a query in Athena I'm getting this error:

`HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be coerced. The column 'event_features' in table 'raw' is declared as type 'string', but partition '___' declared column 'event_features' as type 'array<string>'.`

Indeed I checked and the values for that column can be:

`[]`  which I understand is treated as string not empty array

or

`[{'type':'value'},{'type':'value'}]` which is then correctly interpreted as array

Why would the crawler decide on string even though it's clearly an array of JSON structures? What can I do to fix it? I can't find an option to force column type as array/struct..

Strangely a similar column `event_metrics` has exactly the same value types (sometimes `[]` sometimes array of jsons) and is defined correctly as array

I reviewed some other questions on StackOverlow and selected this setting in the crawler:

`Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.`

But the type of the column did not change..

---edit
The only thing that comes to my mind is to write a custom classifier but hopefully I can avoid that